# Excel function to dynamically SUM UP data based on matching rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with **metrics** shown as rows and **month** shown as columns.
Example is below:

| *Quarter* | *2022-01-01* | *2022-01-01* | *2022-01-01* | *2022-04-01* | *2022-04-01* | *2022-04-01* | *2022-07-01* | *2022-07-01* | *2022-07-01* | *2022-10-01* | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Month* | *2022-01-01* | *2022-02-01* | *2022-03-01* | *2022-04-01* | *2022-05-01* | *2022-06-01* | *2022-07-01* | *2022-08-01* | *2022-09-01* | *2022-10-01* | 2022-11-01 | 2022-12-01 |
| Metrics | **Jan 2022** | **Feb 2022** | **Mar 2022** | **Apr 2022** | **May 2022** | **Jun 2022** | **Jul 2022** | **Aug 2022** | **Sep 2022** | **Oct 2022** | **Nov 2022** | **Dec 2022** |
| **Revenue** | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 500 | 500 | 500 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **Cost** | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 0 | 5 | 10 |

I want to have a dynamic summary table of quarterly data. I can use sumifs and look up the quarter month using this function:
SUMIFS([Value row range],[Quarter range],[Quarter wanted])

However, i still have to manually select the correct value row range to sum. Is it possible to select the entire table and then match the correct row based on matching labels (metric in this case)?

| **Insert Report Month** | **Dec-22** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Last 3 quarter report** |  |  |  |
| **Metrics** | **Q2 2022** | **Q3 2022** | **Q4 2022** |
| **Revenue** | 1500 | 300 | 0 |
| **Cost** | 30 | 60 | 15 |

I'm aware of the index & match function, but it only looks for the first match and does not sum up all months in the same quarter.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What version of Excel? Also, can you reformat this into a "real" Table (your "Table" has a number of columns with identical headers, which is not allowed in a real "Table").

Comment: Thanks, i'm using excel on Mac, version 16.66. The table starts from the 3rd row. The 2 rows above to represent the month and quarter the 3rd row fall into. I use the quarter row to match the desired quarter in the sumifs function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel 365 for MAC should have the `BYCOL` function,

Given:

- Your data table is a `Table` named `Metrics`
- `Report_Month` is a Named Range containing a "real date" in the month of the final month of the desired quarter.

The following formula will return your output and will adjust as you add columns to the data table.

```
A11: =Metrics[[#All],[Metrics]]
B11: =LET(x,EDATE(Report_Month,SEQUENCE(,3,-6,3)),TEXT(MONTH(x)/3,"\Q0 ") & YEAR(x))
```

```
B12: =BYCOL(XLOOKUP(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(Report_Month),MONTH(Report_Month)-9+SEQUENCE(3,,1,1)+SEQUENCE(,3,0,3),1),"mmm-yy"),Metrics[#Headers],INDEX(Metrics,XMATCH(A12,Metrics[Metrics]),0)),LAMBDA(arr,SUM(arr)))
```

Select `B12` and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

***Notes***

```
DATE(YEAR(Report_Month),MONTH(Report_Month)-9+SEQUENCE(3,,1,1)+SEQUENCE(,3,0,3),1)
```

creates a matrix of the previous nine month starting dates with each column consisting of a given quarter:

So for `12/1/2022` =>
[image]

- The `TEXT` function then formats the same as the column headers in the Metrics table.
- `XLOOKUP` will then return the appropriate columns from the table into that matrix, and using the `BYCOL` allows us to `SUM` by column which is the relevant quarter.

Comment: thanks so much! this is a new method that i have never heard of! will try this out!